# How to get an SSL certificate for deployment for a web app that i made with React

Tags: reactjs, ssl, heroku, https, certificate

I made a react web app and deployed to heroku. When you use the heroku original url it uses https and it has its own SSL certificate. But I am using a custom domain `www.xfinitynet.net`. And I would like to mark that site as secured and to be served over https  because I need to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` and that function it seems to work just over https.
I would like to know how i can get a certificate, so i can upload to heroku without using the automate certificate option that heroku offers.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely going to need a CDN, point your custom URL to the CDN and associate the SSL certificate for your domain name with the CDN. The CDN source will need to be your deployed React site (static assets). Here are some links that might give you an idea:

[Heroku AWS CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn)

[React CDN deployment](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-guide-to-deploying-your-react-app-with-aws-s3-including-https-a-custom-domain-a-cdn-and-58245251f081)